# Mapping numpy arrays into pandas DataFrame results in ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a dictionary with keys: arrays, such as:

```
In[0]:  arrs = {
  ...:      'a': np.array([1, 2, 3]),
  ...:      'b': np.array([4, 5, 6])
        }
```

And a pandas DataFrame whose index contains these keys:

```
 In[1]:  df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abc'), columns = list('def'))
   ...:  df
Out[1]:
        d   e   f
    a   NaN NaN NaN
    b   NaN NaN NaN
    c   NaN NaN Na
```

I would like to populate the DataFrame with the values from the array dictionary.

This works:

```
In[2]:  for idx in ['a', 'b']:
  ...:      df.loc[idx, :] = arrs[idx]
  ...:  df
Out[2]: 

            d   e   f  
       a    1   2   3  
       b    4   5   6  
       c    NaN NaN NaN
```

Which is fine, but I would like to vectorize the operation. I tried what I thought would work:

```
In[3]:  df.loc[('a', 'b'), :] = df.loc[('a', 'b'), :].index.map(lambda x: arrs[x])
```

But this results in a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (2,3)
```

Why is my mapping only counting the number of arrays, and not actually seeing the *shape* of the arrays?

Comment: You can't 'vectorize' dictionary access.  Python dictionary values are accessed one by one.  There may be code that hides such access, but it still steps through the keys (that includes `map`).  Well, there is an exception - dictionary `keys()`, `items()` and `values()` produce list generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DataFrame` constructor on your dictionary, then `update` the first `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

df.update(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(arrs, orient='index', columns=['d', 'e', 'f']))
```

#### Output: `df`

```
     d    e    f
a    1    2    3
b    4    5    6
c  NaN  NaN  NaN
```